# What exactly is the EPWING format and how useful is it to a Japanese language learner?

Tags: discussion

I came across the EPWING format when I was installing Yomichan. [This](http://unicorn.ike.tottori-u.ac.jp/murakami/paper/INTERNATIONAL/IWSLT_2007/main/node9.html) is an explanation of the format. I understand the definition but I couldn't find examples of the formatting style so I'm not quite able to see the advantages.

Why is this format useful to someone learning Japanese (using Anki)?

(I saw forum posts asking for particular dictionaries in the EPWING format. Having an EPWING format dictionary for Yomichan apparently boosts its usability?)

Answer (score 1):

EPWING is a file format, so it is not directly applicable to a language learner any more than learning the inner workings of adobe's PDF format is.

If you're a programmer writing a japanese dictionary or flashcard program, it may be worth learning the EPWING format and figuring out how to support it.

---

On the other hand, if you are using a tool which supports EPWING, it may be worth looking at EPWING-formatted dictionaries.

The comments about Yomichan are probably related to the fact that *most* freely available tools are based around the EDICT (or JMDICT) dictionaries, which lack some correlation features you want for a language like Japanese such as associating particular kanji readings with particular shades of meaning.